# Mistake for In-App Purchase Tutorial at Microsoft Website

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I try to implement in-app purchase for a Metro app. I follow the tutorial right here.

[C# code for in-app purchase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694067.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

The C# code is

```
function AppInit()
{
    // some app initialization functions 

    // Get the license info
    // The next line is commented out for testing.
    // licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;

    // The next line is commented out for production/release.       
    licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;

    // other app initialization functions
}
```

But, there are no `function` keyword in C#. This is mistake? If so, what is the correct code suppose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial appears to be mistakenly showing the javascript version of the code. I have my license initialization code inside of the App class, in the OnLaunched() function:

```
    protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active

        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
#if DEBUG
            licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
#else
            licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
#endif

            // other init here...
        }
    }
```